# Homebrew Installation Problems

Tags: macos, homebrew

I am trying to install Homebrew using the terminal using the command :

ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"

But I just keep on getting this error:

==> Downloading and installing Homebrew...
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: ___strlcpy_chk
  Referenced from: /usr/local/git/bin/git
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: ___strlcpy_chk
  Referenced from: /usr/local/git/bin/git
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

Failed during: git init -q

I was unable to find a solution to this problem exaclty and alternative installs isn't working for me. 
Help appreciated.